# Reading in data frames seems to be data table and data frame - how to add new datafile as new element into this list of tables?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, datatable

I have read in nine data tables (previously made in R) into a list `datalist` in R:

```
library(data.table)

path <- "C:/Users/Lies/datafiles"
files<-list.files(path,full.names=T)
datalist <- list()
l <- length(files)
trolls <-{c("M02","M03","M04","M05","M06","M07","M08","M09", "M10")}
for (x in 1:l){
  datalist[[x]] <- fread(files[x], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  names(datalist)[x] <- trolls[x]
  datalist[[x]]$time <- as.POSIXct(datalist[[x]]$time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
}
```

However, reading in the datafiles into the list: each element seems to be a data.table AND a data.frame.

[image: Structure of datalist]

In a next step I remove two colums `pressure` and `level` by means of the following code. This way, all the elements of the list have the same structure as the table `M01` I want to add.

```
datalist <-lapply(datalist, '[', , -c(2,3))
```

I have a data file called `M01` with the same structure as the others, that **I want to add to `datalist` as the first element.**

But this seems not to work with the following code:

```
datalist2 <- c(M01, datalist)
```

Then this is the structure of this list `datalist2`:

[image: structure of datalist2]

How to solve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Try `c(list(M01), datalist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to append. An option is to assign with a name

```
datalist[["M01"]] <- M01
```

If we want to convert the `data.table` to `data.frame`, either use `setDF` or `as.data.frame`

```
datalist <- lapply(datalist, setDF)
```

Or

```
datalist <- lapply(datalist, as.data.frame)
```

---

But, this would add the list element as a new entry at the last

Another option is to create 'datalist2' with one element more than 'datalist'

```
 datalist2 <- vector('list', length(datalist) + 1)
 datalist2[[1]] <- M01
 datalist2[-1] <- datalist
```

---

Or if needs to be at the top, wrap the M01 object in a `list` and then use `c`

```
datalist2 <- c(M01 = list(M01), datalist)
```

---

When we do

```
 c(M01, datalist)
```

it `unclass`, the `data.frame` as it is also a `list` of equal length columns, and the column as a unit gets appended instead of the `data.frame` as a single unit

Comment: Yes thanks! But still, the class of the other elements (M02 to M10) are `class(datalist2[[2]])` gives `"data.table" "data.frame"`, while `M01` (the one I added) is just `data.frame`. How about that?

Comment: @Lies Because you read the data as a data.table with `fread`.  If you want to convert to `data.frame`, either use `setDF` or `as.data.frame`